# Open parquet from GCS using local Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

i have a folder on Google Cloud Storage with several parquet files. I installed in my VM pyspark and now i want to read the parquet files. Here's my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "40g") \
        .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '2001') \
        .config("spark.jars", "~/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar")\
        .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
# using SQLContext to read parquet file
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
# to read parquet file
filename = "gs://path/to/parquet"
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename)
print(df.head())
```

When i run it, it gives me the following error:

```
WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
```

To install pyspark i followed this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-get-started-with-pyspark-1adc142456ec

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read from GCS like [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#reading_from_cloud_storage) and then passing the data that you read? I do not think that you can read directly with pyspark.

I've been reading around about the error and in some instances it is raised when the file is not reachable or the path is incorrect. I think that might be it.